# Period of the function cos (2tanx)+cos (2cotx)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The answer is given as pi/2 . Is it because this function is undefined after every interval of pi/2 or is there some other explanation.

Comment: No. The function $\tan(x)-x$ is also undefined for all $(k+1)\pi/2$ but is aperiodic.

Comment: @CyborgOctopus: no, they don't.

Comment: No. It is because tangent and cotangent both have period $\pi$. We can halve that because $\tan(x+\pi/2)=-\cot x$ and cosine is even ($\cos(-\alpha)=\cos\alpha$ for all $\alpha$). If you understand why these observations help, please update the question to reflect that. Otherwise your post may be viewed as bit lacking of context. See [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tan\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)=-\cot x$$ and $$\cot\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)=-\tan x.$$

As the cosine is an even function, the minus signs are absorbed and the period is at most $\dfrac\pi2$, as

$$f\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)=f(x).$$

---

We can confirm that this is the smallest period from the fact that the function has an unbounded slope only at the multiples of $\dfrac\pi2$.